# Need more amps to charge a phone

Tags: solar-cell, amperage

I am trying to charge my phone (Samsung galaxy S6) using solar power, I have the output connected to a circuit that takes it from around 20 volts down to about 5.5 volts. When i plug my phone into the circuit it says it is charging but proceeds to loose power. The circuit generates about 100 milliamps but this is not enough. how can I increase the amps of the circuit.

Comment: ::Boggle:: Your solar cell generates 100Amps at 20 volts and it is not enough?

Comment: 100 A at 5 V = 500 W. Phone chargers are typically 5 W or so. And you want more? Has it melted yet?

Comment: sorry not amps milliamps

Comment: Please provide details about the solar panel AND the circuit that is bucking down to 5.5V.

Comment: I don't know much about the solar panels, they are Sunforce power sports charger, and I am using a car charger that you would plug a USB cable into to charge your phone.

Comment: For the panel, do you have a model number, or does the panel say on it somewhere what the Voc and Isc are? Or Vmp or Vmpp? Those terms mean Voc=open-circuit voltage. Isc=short=-circuit current. Vmp=maximum power voltage.

Comment: The panels are old and the stickers have fallen off, so I don't know.

Comment: The only two models of power sports panels I can find after a quick search are 1.5W and 1W. That is not enough for your charger. So you would need a bigger panel. I would suggest at least 15W, and 20 might be a safer bet. Be warned that the panel voltage can be much higher than a car battery and may cause your charger to fail permanently (along with smoke or even, possibly, flames). Without detailed specifications, nobody is going to be able to check if the parts you choose are compatible.

Comment: I am using two panels, but thanks i will look for a better panel.

Comment: would it charge a battery pack? Then i could use the battery pack to charge the phone.

Comment: Too many unknowns to answer. If you have a specific battery pack and a specific charger with detailed specs, it might be possible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need 5.5 volts for charging, and you're not getting enough *current*, this means that you're also not getting enough *power*. P=I*V. You can't just "fix" that without breaking a couple of laws of physics.

The only solution is to get a bigger and/or better solar panel.

Since you're only getting about 100 mA, it's not worth trying to improve the efficiency of the converter. It would get you up to at most something like 150 mA.